# Does static initialization fiasco occurs only in c++?

Tags: c++, static, static-order-fiasco

I just found out that there is static initialization fiasco problem in c++, I am just curious, is this only c++ problem? or maybe this problem is already fixed even in c++?

Comment: It certainly isn't fixed in c++ today, though work-arounds do exist.

Comment: It's also a problem in c, not only c++.

Comment: The workaround of holding a static variable in an accessor reference function (effectively, a singleton) is a robust alternative.  Helps avoid possibly superfluous pre-main initialization, and the embarrassing (but hard to correct... that ship has sailed) fiasco problem.  However, may cause atexit problems, depending on how much work is done post-main / exit shutdown.

Comment: The "static initialization fiasco" is much overrated.

Comment: @PeteBecker I disagree. If you've ever worked with a code base riddled with singletons that end up directly or indirectly depending on eachother, then it's a very real problem that causes real pain. Sure, just get rid of the singletons is a solution, but may be a hard one to achieve when you have 500k lines of code all tangled up with them :(

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- sure, badly written code can be hard to get right. It's a poor carpenter who blames his tools.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi, each unit can have `initialization` and `finalization` section. (Unit is single source file).

Provided that there are no circular dependencies between units, `initialization` of dependency would come before than `initialization` of dependent module. Finalization order is reverse.

I think this is an example of that the problem could have been avoided.